# Using stackexchange to post your own insights Q & A style

Tags: discussion, etiquette, self-answer

On one of my posts, where I posted an answer at the same time that I asked a question, I got several negative votes for someone telling me not to use the site for my personal notes.

It was a sort of post where I had something that confused me yesterday, which no longer confused me.

I would be surprised though, if it were against stackexchange policy, to use the site the way I was - on every question there is a prompt saying " share your knowledge Q&A style".

An answer to [Answering your own question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11832/answering-your-own-question) says  "do not omit important information from a question", which is something that I tend to do when making my own notes.  Thus it is probably impolite to use stackexchange in this way.

My question is whether this behavior could get me suspended - If not I plan to make many more posts of this type. I find it very useful to note down in a place that I can access anywhere, what was confusing me because I will tend to forget a month later what was confusing me.

Comment: If your point is to use MSE to make a compendium of notes (as your last sentence seems to indicate), then I'd expect that will get a fairly poor reception; regardless of what the FAQ / meta say, the practice seems to be that there is a *very* high threshold that self-answered questions must meet in order to have a good response. This won't get you suspended without some egregious wrong-doing, but could get you downvotes.

Comment: The already linked (maybe due to earlier deleted comments? the following is the first posting of it that appears) question http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23348/writing-a-solution-manual-for-textbooks is very similar and the same answers apply.

Comment: I also interpreted the  "share your knowledge Q&A style" as the OP did.